# make 'href' tag point to separate item in a loop

Tags: php, download

Please I want to create a separate download link to file in a folder, I displayed the title from the database in a loop.

```
$sql = "select title from item 
        where own_id = {$id} and item_type='lecture'  ";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<a href='http://localhost/zippedguide/download/book/way.pdf.zip'>"."Download" ."</a>"."  ".$rows['title']."<br> ";
    }
}
```

I want the 'href' to point each file not just one as shown

Answer (score 0):

try `echo "<input type='text'>";`
or
try : `echo "<input type=\"text\">";`

Answer (score 0):

Hi I assume the files name is like this [title].pdf.zip so your code should be :

```
$sql = "select title from item 
        where own_id = {$id} and item_type='lecture'  ";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<a href='http://localhost/zippedguide/download/book/".$rows['title'].".pdf.zip'>"."Download" ."</a>"."  ".$rows['title']."<br> ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Just what I want